# Find Mismatched Data Between Two Different Dataframe Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two columns, both from different dataframes. The issue is that these columns are not in the same order.

Given the two dataframes below:

```
df1
index Letter
  1    C,D,X
  2    E,F
  3    A,B


df2
index Letter
  1    A
  2    C,D
  3    F
```

I want to identify all data that these two dataframes do not have in common. For example, one dataframe has 'A,B' while the other one has only 'A'. I am trying to flag the missing 'B' in df2. Would the best approach be to split each row of 'Letter' into a list of lists and then create a dictionary to compare?

Comment: so index here mean nothing ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben correct, only the data. Which is why I am wondering if it is even possible with pandas